# How do I statically link SDL on Windows with MinGW?

Tags: c++, sdl, static-linking

See title. I'm using Code::Blocks. Googling results in info involving the sdl-config sh script, which I obviously can't use on Windows.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620884/static-linking-of-sdl2-libraries for SDL 2/MinGW/Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0):

[How to statically compile an SDL game on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115813/how-to-statically-compile-an-sdl-game-on-windows)

Comment: That doesn't offer a solution not involving the sh script. Or does it? I'm still learning C++ and the relatively complex building system is the main thing that frustrates me.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. You might want to research MSYS. http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS